# Explanation for activate_control_app in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone explain the use of `activate_control_app` in `puma.rb`? I am new to rails and face issue in running rails app. I can get the app running once I comment out this line.

Answer (score 1):

`activate_control_app` will enable the [Control/Status server](https://github.com/puma/puma#controlstatus-server) in puma. It can also be enabled via the command line:

```
puma --control-url tcp://127.0.0.1:9293 --control-token foo
```

is equivalent to

```rb
#config/puma.rb
activate_control_app "tcp://127.0.0.1:9293", { auth_token: "foo" }
```

If you're not using the control server, you can safely comment out that line.

Comment: The issue that I get is "Address already in use" if I dont comment out activate_control_app. Could it be using the same 3000 port that rails is using?

Comment: If you're specifying port 3000 in `activate_control_app`, then yes absolutely.

Comment: No I am not specifying port 3000.

Comment: A bit silly that the documentation lacks basic info on `activate_control_app` in puma.rb.